# Netsuite scriptContext.oldRecord and scriptContext.newRecord return the same thing

Tags: netsuite

Trying to get the new data from a submitted sales_order to post it to a remote db. 
Trying to make that little snippet work first.

for some reasons both statuses come back identical.

[image]

```
/**
 * User Event 2.0 example detailing usage of the Submit events
 *
  @NApiVersion 2.x
  @NModuleScope SameAccount
  @NScriptType UserEventScript
  @appliedtorecord salesorder
 */

define(['N/runtime'], function(runtime) {
  var exports = {};

  function afterSubmit(scriptContext) {
    var salesOrder = scriptContext.newRecord;
    var prevSalesOrder = scriptContext.oldRecord;

    var status = salesOrder.getValue({ fieldId: 'status' });
    var prevStatus = prevSalesOrder.getValue({ fieldId: 'status' });

    log.audit({ title: 'New', details: status });
    log.audit({ title: 'Old', details: prevStatus });
  }

  exports.afterSubmit = afterSubmit;
  return exports;
});
```

Comment: How are you updating the sales order? is that the old or new status?

Comment: Hi @EmersonMinero, To update the status I just edit the salesOrder, select another option in the dropdown for status and save.
This is the old value, it always returns the old one.

Comment: After digging a little more I realized that the `status` that I was looking at is not changing because the one that gets changed is `orderstatus`. Not sure why the customer changed that field. thanks @EmersonMinero.

Comment: I see, at least you resolved the issue. You're welcome.